# After running any npm command following message is shown in cmd

Tags: npm

After running any npm command following message is shown in cmd

```
C:\Users\LENOVOG50>npm -v

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: can you show the output of commands, `node -v`, `npm -v`? Also, give details of the Environment variables and copy-paste here their details, so we can find where is an error. put screenshots if possible and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Node is not installed, or not the path in environment or system variables was not entered.

Verify that this path exists: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`